# javascript equivalent of this php snippet

Tags: javascript, php, sha512

Given this php:

```
 $hash = hash('sha512', $salt . $password, TRUE);
 /* point A */
 $hash = hash('sha512', $hash . $password, TRUE);
 /* point B */
```

I've written this javascript:

```
let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
hash.update(salt + password);
let buffer = hash.digest();
 /* point A */
 hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
 hash.update(buffer.toString() + password);
 buffer = hash.digest();
 /* point B */
```

At point A buffer has the same value in PHP and Javascript for all salt and password strings. But at point B they are different so there is something wrong with my second call to hash.update. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: When you convert a buffer full of 8-bit values to a string, the values will be interpreted as Unicode.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy - I also tried: hash.update(buffer + Buffer.from(password)); but that's not the same either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

OK I think I've got it.

```
let hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
hash.update(salt + password);
let buffer = hash.digest();
/* point A */
hash = crypto.createHash('sha512');
hash.update(Buffer.concat([buffer, Buffer.from(password)]));
buffer = hash.digest();
/* point B */
```